# Prove that we get a norm from a definition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V := C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to {\rm I\!R}$. I want to prove that we get a norm  $\|·\|_\infty$ on V by  $\|f||_\infty := \max\{|f(x)| \mid x\in[0,1]\}$.
I don't understand the notation "$V := C[0,1]$" either. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: It is read as " $V$ is by definition $C[0,1]$"

Comment: Yes but I don't know what $C[0,1]$ is.

Comment: It is written in the first sentence!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $V:=C[0,1]$ is just defining $V$ to be $C[0,1]$, which is the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. To prove that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is a norm, you need to show that it satisfies the conditions that norms must satisfy. Namely, you need to show:

1. $\|f\|_\infty\ge0$ for every $f\in V$;
2. $\|f\|_\infty=0$ implies $f=0$ (i.e., $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in[0,1]$);
3. $\|\alpha f\|_\infty = |\alpha|\|f\|_\infty$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and every $f\in V$;
4. $\|f+g\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty +\|g\|_\infty$ for every $f,g\in V$.

Each of these follow from the definition and the corresponding properties for the absolute value of a real number.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to prove number 2. from what we have?

Comment: @Maddude Yes, and it is actually trivial. If $\|f\|_\infty = 0$, then $\sup\{|f(x)| : x\in [0,1]\} = 0$. What does that mean?

Comment: How do you know that sup{$|f(x)| | x ∈ [0,1]$} = 0 ?

Comment: @Maddude What does $\|f\|_\infty=0$ mean?

Comment: It means $max |f_i|$

Comment: @Maddude No, it means $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=0$. What can you then say about $f(0)$? What about $f(1)$? What about $f(x)$ for any $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Thus i would say it is $f(x) = 0$ for any $x ∈ [0,1]$